# NotificationCompat.Builder addAction in pre JellyBean Androids?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification with a addidional action so user is able to go to the main activity by clicking the main notification or stop the service clicking the secondary (extented) notification. This works fine for post JellyBean Androids (4.1+). How to achieve similar functionality in older systems (API 11+)?

```
       noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("service")
                .setContentText("running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Stop", pIntent)

                .build();

        startForeground(12345, noti);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

> Builder class for NotificationCompat objects. Allows easier control
>   over all the flags, as well as help constructing the typical
>   notification layouts.
>
> On platform versions that don't offer expanded notifications, methods
>   that depend on expanded notifications have no effect.
>
> For example, action buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android
>   4.1. Action buttons depend on expanded notifications, which are only available in Android 4.1 and later.
>
> For this reason, you should always ensure that UI controls in a
>   notification are also available in an Activity in your app, and you
>   should always start that Activity when users click the notification.
>   To do this, use the setContentIntent() method.

and from the `addAction()`:

> Add an action to this notification. Actions are typically displayed by
>   the system as a button adjacent to the notification content.  Action
>   buttons won't appear on platforms prior to Android 4.1. Action buttons
>   depend on expanded notifications, which are only available in Android
>   4.1 and later. To ensure that an action button's functionality is always available, first implement the functionality in the Activity
>   that starts when a user clicks the notification (see
>   setContentIntent()), and then enhance the notification by implementing
>   the same functionality with addAction().

I found [this](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/) tutorial that you might find useful.

Comment: I've read the docs before posting this, but I hoping for some solution.